# Sharing button is not showing on Account detail page in Lighting Experience

Tags: sharing

I can see the sharing button for Account object in the Edit Layout but it's not showing in the detail page. Can anybody please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

This feature (manual sharing) doesn't currently exist in Lightning. It's [much-requested](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LmluQAC) on the Idea Exchange.

If you're not able to get around this need or use Classic for manual-sharing workflows, you'll have to use a third-party application. There's an open-source one [available](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFp0ZUAT) from Salesforce Labs, for example (disclaimer: I have no experience with this app personally).

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. However, I have installed "Lightning Sharing" app but i didn't see the sharing button for Account object and it is available for only custom object exist in the app. Is there any custom solution for this? Please let me know on this.

Comment: @user66565 I haven't used that app myself. Based on its AppExchange listing, you need to do some configuration to surface the Sharing button for each object.